# port forwarding on OSX without using the terminal

Tags: macos, port-forwarding

Can anyone tell me if there exists an app that simplifies setting up port forwarding on OSX without using the terminal?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by port forwarding? Are you using your Mac as a router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application [Port Map](http://www.codingmonkeys.de/portmap/) may help you to easily configure ports if you have an UPnP router.